# Order a column by highest to lowest counts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to order the [desc] column by highest count frequency to lowest. The [desc] column is a referral location for example a hospital. If hospital1 occurs the most I want that grouped at the top of my list and the next highest below that, ect..

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE_NUM,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,UNIT_ID,REF_SOURCE_ID,[DESC]
FROM CDCLIENT
INNER JOIN CDTBL1 ON CDCLIENT.REF_SOURCE_ID = CDTBL1.ID
INNER JOIN CDCLSVC ON CDCLSVC.CLIENT_ID = CDCLIENT.ID
WHERE TYPE = 'REF'
AND STATUS_FLAG = 'A'
ORDER BY [DESC] DESC
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: Below is a sample output. There are only 12568 total rows. The counts are not correct. I am trying to get a count of how many times the [desc] occurs and order from largest count to smallest.
CASE_NUM UNIT_ID REF_SOURCE_ID DESC TEST
4242 4121 JA HOSPITAL1 10540
5778 4121 J2 HOSPITAL2 10513
1456 4121 IC HOSPITAL3 10094
5869 4121 IE HOSPITAL4 10075
7286 4121 JA HOSPITAL5 9928
7456 4121 IX HOSPITAL6 9629
9685 4121 JA HOSPITAL7 8915

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you intend:

```
SELECT CASE_NUM, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, UNIT_ID, REF_SOURCE_ID, [DESC]
FROM CDCLIENT INNER JOIN
     CDTBL1
     ON CDCLIENT.REF_SOURCE_ID = CDTBL1.ID INNER JOIN
     CDCLSVC
     ON CDCLSVC.CLIENT_ID = CDCLIENT.ID
WHERE TYPE = 'REF' AND STATUS_FLAG = 'A'
GROUP BY CASE_NUM, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, UNIT_ID, REF_SOURCE_ID, [DESC]
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This does an aggregation and then orders by the count.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE_NUM,
                LAST_NAME,
                FIRST_NAME,
                UNIT_ID,
                REF_SOURCE_ID,
                [DESC],
                COUNT(DISTINCT [DESC]) OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_NUM,
                                                         LAST_NAME,
                                                         FIRST_NAME,
                                                         UNIT_ID,
                                                         REF_SOURCE_ID) As NumberOfDescs
FROM CDCLIENT
INNER JOIN CDTBL1 ON CDCLIENT.REF_SOURCE_ID = CDTBL1.ID
INNER JOIN CDCLSVC ON CDCLSVC.CLIENT_ID = CDCLIENT.ID
WHERE TYPE = 'REF'
AND STATUS_FLAG = 'A'
ORDER BY NumberOfDescs DESC
```